# Is there a Raspberry Pi command for fetching files via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm in a team taking part in the Astro Pi competition. Our experiment uses AI to process satellite images - but that isn't relevant to the question.

I need a method for a Raspberry Pi to fetch a file from another Pi - rather like the `scp` command (secure copy) but that fetches a file as opposed to sending one. Is there a command for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better asked on SuperUser, it is not about programming, not even about the Raspberry Pi (the answer will work on anything from a phone to a supercomputer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `scp` can do that.
Just use the following syntax:

```
$ scp username@from_the_other_Pi:/remote/directory/file  /local/directory/file
```

And you're done!

Comment: OP wants to fetch a file, or maybe some files. The command you suggest recursively fetches entire directories.

Comment: You're right, just edited.

Comment: I was referring to the `-r` as well :-)